# Как составить функцию, чтобы вставить число на k позицию в массиве

Tags: массивы, visual-c++, c++

Как составить функцию в с++, чтобы вставить число на k позицию в массиве

Answer (score 1):

массив или вектор? Если вектор, то здесь все очень просто - там есть готовый метод [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/), который получает два параметра - позицию вставки и собственно сам элемент. Использование класса std::vector в современном с++ - это стандарт. И этот класс самый что не на есть стандартный класс. Если Ваш с++ компилятор не поддерживает этот класс, выкиньте компилятор.

Если же хочется на "голых массивах", то здесь все сложнее. Алгоритм такой - вначале выделяется новый массив, на один элемент больше, дальше копируются все элементы до места вставки, потом сам элемент, а потом элементы после вставки с сдвигом на один элемент. А старый массив уничтожается. Код могу написать, но это на самом то деле уже не плюсы будут, а чистый си.